# How can I change the appearance of the "figure" counter?

Tags: counters

In the following code the `figure` number is shown as `1.1`. How can I change the `figure` number format to `1-1`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
test
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{10.png} \caption{} \label{handle}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{handle}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you want to change it only in ref? what about in caption (`Figure 1.1: caption`)?

Comment: @touhami I want to change it everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\ifnum \value{chapter}>0 \thechapter-\fi \arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
test
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{myfoto} \caption{bla} \label{handle}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{handle}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: it does not work for me with xelatex.

Comment: it shows only one number. But I want both numbers like `1-1`.

Comment: Will this method reset the within-chapter `figure` number back to "1" at the start of every chapter?

Comment: @Mico no, it doesn't but the class book does so yes the figure counter will be reset at every (unstarred) chapter start.

Comment: @Mico I am voting for reopening this question. here the O.P. want to change the format of counter.

Comment: @touhami - You're right. I've joined in on the re-open drive. :-) I've also edited the posting's title since it's not about `\ref` per se.